# How do I start vim with syntax highlighting off?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

How do I start vim with syntax highlighting off?
Vim is taking a long time to highlight syntax for large XML files for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can start vim with

```
vim -c 'syn off'
```

Or you can specify that it should turn it off for large XML files by making an ftplugin file. For instance put

```
if getfsize(expand('%')) > 400000
    syntax off
endif
```

in a file named `~/.vim/ftplugin/xml.vim`

Comment: I use: vim --clean -c "syntax off" large-file.sql - this disables syntax highlighting and plugins/themes and can help speed things even further

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable syntax highlighting. You can do that (and few additional options that can be useful in such situation) by following [this instruction on Vi SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/149/how-can-i-open-very-large-files-with-good-performance).